# RandSeed not working?

Tags: delphi

```
procedure RandSeed();
var datum: TDateTime;
var hodina,minuta,sekunda,milisekunda: Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(datum,hodina,minuta,sekunda,milisekunda);
  RandSeed := milisekunda;
end;
```

This code doesn't work. It says 'left side cannot be assigned to' when I try compiling it. Anyone knows why? Thanks.

EDIT: I've changed my code as following based on your tips and it works now, thanks a lot!

```
procedure RandSeed();
var hodina,minuta,sekunda,milisekunda: Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(now,hodina,minuta,sekunda,milisekunda);
  System.RandSeed := milisekunda;
end;
```

Comment: It's disappointing that the two answers that explain the problem were deleted, and that the answer which fails to do that is the one that remains. TLama, Jason: it doesn't matter if your answer is not first. If it is better then I for one will up vote it!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why my answer fails?

Comment: @RRUZ You have edited it now. The original version explained nothing and just said "do this and it works". You fixed that just before the grace period was up. I would like to encourage the other answerers to stick to their guns and not be frightened off by fast answerers (e.g. like me!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems: First, as RRUZ mentions, you have a naming conflict with the predefined `System.RandSeed`. The conflict is caused by the fact you're trying to return a value from a *procedure*. (See below.)

The second reason is, as I said, you're trying to return a value from a procedure. You need a function instead.

```
function RandSeed: Word;
var 
  datum: TDateTime;
var 
  hodina,minuta,sekunda,milisekunda: Word;
begin
  DecodeTime(datum,hodina,minuta,sekunda,milisekunda);
  RandSeed := milisekunda;
  // Better (and more modern) would be
  // Result := milisekunda;
end;
```

If your intent is to replace the internal `RandSeed` variable with your own function, this will work. If your intent is just to use your function to assign a value to the existing `RandSeed` variable, change your procedure to contain::

```
System.RandSeed := millisekunda;
```

Answer (score 7):

To assign a value to the [`RandSeed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/System.RandSeed) variable you must specify the full qualified  name like this `System.RandSeed` to avoid the conflict name with your own procedure `RandSeed` or just rename your procedure.

Comment: +1. Good catch - I missed the name conflict because `System.RandSeed` is a *variable* and not a function.